# Proof that composition of equivalence relations R and S is transitive if and only if R∘S=S∘R

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

Proof that composition of equivalence relations $R$ and $S$ is transitive if and only if $R$∘$S$ = $S$∘$R$.

I'm trying to understand how it could be proved: as I know composition of transitive is transitive, but I have no idea what should be done next.

Comment: Now you need to assume that $R\circ S$ is transitive, and prove that $R\circ S=S\circ R$; then assume $R\circ S=S\circ R$, and prove that $R\circ S$ is transitive.

Answer (score 1):

We use the fact that for every reflexive binary relations $R, S$ on a set, $R \subseteq R \circ S$ and $R \subseteq S \circ R$, and that $R$ is transitive iff $R \circ R = R$.

$(\Rightarrow:)$
Let us suppose that $R \circ S$ is transitive and let $(a,c) \in R \circ S$.
Then, for some $b$, we have $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in S$.
Since the relations are symmetric, $(c,b) \in S$ and $(b,a) \in R$, from which it follows by an earlier remark that $(c,b) \in R \circ S$ and $(b,a) \in R \circ S$.
Now, by hypothesis, it follows that $(c,a) \in R \circ S$, whence $(a,c) \in S \circ R$.
We conclude that $R \circ S \subseteq S \circ R$.

The reverse inclusion follows from $S \circ R \subseteq R \circ S \circ R \circ S = R \circ S$, by hypothesis.
So $R \circ S = S \circ R$.

$(\Leftarrow:)$
Suppose $(a,b), (b,c) \in R \circ S$.
Then, there exist $u,v$ such that
$$a R u S b \quad \text{ and } \quad b R v S c.$$
From $b R v S c$ it follows that $(b,c) \in R \circ S = S \circ R$, and so $(b,c) \in S \circ R$.
Now, from $u S b (S \circ R) c$ it follows that $(u,c) \in S \circ R$, and from $a R u (S \circ R)c$, it follows that $(a,c) \in R \circ (S \circ R) = R \circ (R \circ S) = R \circ S$, and so $R \circ S$ is transitive.

Comment: $(a,b)\in R\circ S$ means $aSuRb$ for some $u$. You probably need $$\begin{aligned}&\exists u,v, aSuRb\land 
bSvRc\\&\overset{R\circ S=S\circ R}{\implies} uRb(S\circ R)c\\&\implies (u,c)\in S\circ R=R\circ S\\&\implies aSu(R\circ S)c\\&\implies 
(a,c)\in R\circ S \end{aligned}$$

Comment: [• a worth noting remark •](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2500648/721644)

Comment: @Invisible That's a matter of convention. Note the [composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) is often done as I did. I'm not sure I understand the remark Graham Kemp made there, but I suppose is considering the composition the other way around and remarking that for a different convention it's just a matter of swapping the symbols in the argument. So with the convention I used (and I think it's the more common one, but that's debatable), I don't need that chain o implications,  but it worth keeping the comment since other people might find it clarifying